# Gnuplot: how to plot date / time chart

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot this kind of data:

- X axis: dates
- Y axis: time lenght

The data would looks like that:

```
22/02 51:10
25/02 63:10
01/03 50:55
23/03 52:10
```

I already done that for the X axis:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m"
```

But I don't know how to manage Y axis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089284/gnuplot-how-to-plot-date-time-chart/5089659#5089659) said, you can only use one timefmt. However, if it is possible to split your data to more columns like this:

```
22/02 51 10
25/02 63 10
01/03 50 55
23/03 52 10
```

you can then plot the time length by direct calculation, like this:

```
plot 'file' u 1:($2 + $3/60)
```

to plot minutes, or like this:

```
plot 'file' u 1:($2/60 + $3/3600)
```

to plot hours.

Comment: +1 nicely done: Also you can automatically split the columns in gnuplot with awk: plot "<awk 'BEGIN{FS=\"[ :]\"} {print $1, $2, $3} ' date_time.dat" u 1:($2/60 + $3/3600) - might be worth appending this to your answer for completeness

Comment: @Tom: I originally had a note for awk but it seemed to me OP is experienced enough to know this. Anyway, now we also have your comment for completeness; thanks! :)

Comment: Very noce solution! Tom answered my question, but your completion is excellent!

Comment: This is useful for increasing time resolution to microseconds. Do you probably know if there is a proper format char for this? Or is there really just this limited formatting language presented in the [Timefmt](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node274.html) docs?

Comment: @Wolf No need for this, gnuplot can handle microseconds (since 4.6?): data `12:34:56.1234567` can be read in with `set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'`.

Comment: @Christoph Yes :) -- in the [4.6 docs](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-22), I read ***`New time/date handling`*** *`Gnuplot now tracks time to millisecond precision[...]`*

Comment: @Wolf Correct, but I just tested and here it works fine with microseconds. I don't know on what this depends on.

Comment: @Christoph I read your *here* as *using `set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'`*. Maybe the example from the docs shows how to restrict the digits to just 3, but does this really make sense? (I only wanted to confirm that milliseconds are accepted in gnuplot 4.6+)

Comment: @Wolf Yes, using `set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'` I could read in data with microseconds precision, like `12:34:56.123456` and `12.34:56.123457`, which are plotted correctly. When reading in times you cannot specify a precision, however I don't know why the gnuplot docs mention milliseconds precision (at one point the talk about *at least* milliseconds precision) The only part where you can explicitely give a precision to the time is for the output, like `set format x '%M:%.3S'`.

Answer (score 3):

From `?xdata`

> There is  currently only one timefmt,
>   which implies that all the time/date
>   columns must  conform to this format.

So you need to alter your data somewhat to conform to one setting.

something like

```
00:00:22/02 51:10:22/02
00:00:25/02 63:10:22/02
00:00:01/03 50:55:22/02
00:00:23/03 52:10:22/02
```

Note that you can use command line tools to do this within gnuplot, see [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile3-e.html)

Once the file is edited you can read it like so

```
set xdata time
set ydata time
set timefmt "%M:%S:%d/%m"
set format x "%d/%m"
set format y "%M:%S"
plot "date_time.dat" u 1:2 w l
```