# Time / date handling in gnuplot 5

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data set

```
0   22/01   5:40.416    07/01   5:59.149
1   29/01   5:49.765    14/01   5:59.036
2   05/02   5:45.675    21/01   5:52.160
3   12/02   5:44.241    28/01   5:55.160
4   19/02   5:49.330    04/02   5:44.065
5   26/02   5:48.044    11/02   5:34.803
```

and I want to plot column 3 as a function of 2 (and also 5 as a function of 4 but that is not the problem). The format are day/month and minutes:seconds.xxx.

In gnuplot 4.6 it was somewhat straightforward to indicate how to read both columns by setting distinct time formats for x and y. A minimal script that worked is:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt x "%d/%m"
set format x "%b"

set ydata time
set timefmt y "%M:%S"
set format y "%M:%S"

plot 'data.dat' using 2:3
```

I recently upgraded to gnuplot 5 and the command `set timefmt x "%d/%m"` (and its `y` equivalent) now give an error. It seems that you cannot put `x` or `y` anymore, and you can only use a single `timefmt` for the whole script.

The [release notes](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html) state that

> Use of time formats to generate axis tick labels is now controlled by
>   `set {xy}tics time` rather than by `set {xy}data time`. Thus prior
>   calls to `set xdata time` or `set timefmt x` are unnecessary for
>   either input or output. These older commands still work, but are
>   deprecated.

I have two issues. First, despite the indication that "older commands still work", I get an error on `set timefmt x "%d/%m"`. Second, and most important, I couldn't figure out how to teach gnuplot how to read my x and y columns using the new commands.

Note: I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089284/gnuplot-how-to-plot-date-time-chart) from 2011 but I don't find it elegant and I want to keep the files with the present format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The improvement they made with this new version actually makes it more flexible. Rather than specify a default time format and then require your columns to fit that format, you can specify a format for each particular time column.  This way you don't have to be consistent, as long as you specify each column's format. You can also use a time format for more than an *x* or *y* axis.

The solution to your question is mentioned in the release notes you quoted, but it doesn't explain it well.  Use the `timecolumn(N,"timeformat")` function, like the following:

```
set xtics time
set format x "%b"

set ytics time
set format y "%M:%S"

plot 'data.dat' using (timecolumn(2, "%d/%m")):(timecolumn(3, "%M:%S"))
```

The `set timefmt` lines have been replaced by this new two-argument `timefunction()`, which allows you to specify the format for each column in the `using` clause. Notice the `()` around the `timecolumn()`. This means that you could (if you wanted) do some math with the time value.  According to the same [5.0 release notes](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/ReleaseNotes_5_0.html):

> Time coordinates are stored internally as the number of seconds relative to the standard unix epoch 1-Jan-1970. Earlier versions of gnuplot used a different epoch internally (1-Jan-2000). This change resolves inconsistencies introduced when time in seconds was generated externally. The epoch convention used by a particular gnuplot installation can be determined using the command `print strftime("%F",0)`. Time is now stored to at least millisecond precision.

Notice the change to `set xtics time`.  The output format for the xtics is the same as in your example, and is different from the input format given by the second argument to `timecolumn()`.  You seem to have more flexibility than before, but the syntax has changed.