# gnuplot - autoscale y axis with filledcurves + xrange + xdata time

Tags: gnuplot

in gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 1 on my old server I used:

```
set term pngcairo transparent truecolor size 190,40
set output "some.png"

unset bmargin
set bmargin 0
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0

unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset y2tics
unset key 
unset title
unset colorbox

set timefmt '%Y-%m'
set xdata time

set style fill transparent solid 0.25 noborder

tt = "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M`"
TIMEFMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
now_secs = strptime(TIMEFMT,tt)
two_years_past = now_secs - 3600.0*24*365*2

eval(sprintf('set xrange ["%s":]',strftime(TIMEFMT,two_years_past)))
set autoscale yfix

plot "datafile" using 1:2 with filledcurves below x1 lw 1 lc rgb "#a7eeeeee" title ''
```

...it produced a graph with y range correctly auto-scaled.

But on my new server with gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3 installed it does not work anymore. It seems they screwed something in the code. The yrange is computed from all x timedata, not over the selected xrange only.

I have no idea how to correct the yrange in this case. It could be computed using the stats command, but the "xdata time" must be switched off before, but in that case I do not know, how to set the right xrange for the stats command.

Regards
Pavel

EDIT:
minimal datafile:

```
2014-01 2
2014-06 6
2015-01 4
2015-06 8
2016-01 6
2016-06 10
```

Comment: Please see the question from yesterday: [Time / date handling in gnuplot 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317275/time-date-handling-in-gnuplot-5)

Comment: Could you please give a minimal data set which allows to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Datafile added. In fact it seems to me, that any filledcurves below are not y - autoscaled now in 5,0 patchlevel 3, so even if I comment out the xrange command

Comment: (I mean the y scale always starts at 0)

Comment: Indeed. I have tested all newer versions (5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5) and none of them creates a correct graph. So the 5.0.1 is the latest version without the bug.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your y-range autoscale issue with gnuplot<=5.0.1 and all versions >5.0.1 to 5.4.0.

Although, gnuplot is not scaling to the full y-data-range as you assumed, but apparently `filledcurves x1` seems to always (auto)scale to 0 unless there is y-data <0.
To me, this looks more like a bug than a feature. I don't see a reason why `filledcurves` should always autoscale to 0.
In contrary to this behaviour, the plotting style `with boxes` will still autoscale in y to the minimum as you want it.

So, as a workaround to keep your desired behaviour you need to add two lines:

```
stats $Data u 2 nooutput
set yrange[STATS_min:]
```

The x-range is already limited when executing the `stats` command, hence you will get the y-minimum in `STATS_min` which you can use to set the y-range.

By the way: I cleaned up your script a bit. Why making a platform-dependent system call for getting the current time, if you have the gnuplot function `time()`? Check `help time`.

**Script:** (works identical for all gnuplot versions >=5.0.0)

```
### adjust time range via current time with proper y autoscale
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2020-01  12
2020-06   6
2021-01   4
2021-06   8
2022-01   6
2022-06  10
EOD

t0            = time(0)          # now, i.e. seconds from Jan, 1st 1970 00:00:00
TwoYearsInSec = 3600*24*365*2    # two years in seconds
myTimeFmt     = "%Y-%m"
set format x "%Y\n%m" timedate
set style fill transparent solid 0.25 noborder
set xrange [t0-TwoYearsInSec:t0]

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set title "undesired y-autoscaling to 0 with filledcurves"
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w filledcurves above x1 lc rgb 0xff0000 not

    set title "workaround to scale to y-minimum"
    stats $Data u 2 nooutput
    set yrange[STATS_min:]
    replot

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 5.4.0)

[image]